# How to get value from the different django model in DTL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, jinja2

I am having 3 different models - `User`, `Thread` and `UserProfile`.

`User` model contains information like `ID, First_name and Last_name`.

`Thread` model contains information like

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    first_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='thread_first_person')
    second_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='thread_second_person')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and `UserProfile` model,

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    custom_user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(default='profile_image/pro.png', upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
```

when I am trying to get all the threads from `Thread` model and pass it from views.py to my HTML template then I can access `User` model fields like -

`{{ thread.second_person.ID}} {{ thread.second_person.First_name}}`

But how can I access `picture` field from `UserProfile` with the help of `custom_user` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused: you say you have three models `User`, `Thread` and `UserProfile`. But inside your `UserProfile` model you reference a `CustomUser` model as the one-to-one relationship for the custom_user field. Then in your `Thread` model you reference a plain `User` model as the FKs for the first_person and second_person fields. Do you have 3 models or 4?

Assuming you only have 3 models, and that `CustomUser` is actually just `User`, then what you're trying to achieve should be doable. However you may need to change your conventions regarding **related names** to best practices in order to do so cleanly.

I have set up the models I think you need roughly below, and the code needed to access the relevant parts of each model within the template layer:

```py
#models.py

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    # User Model Code


class Thread(models.Model):
    first_person = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        related_name='thread_first_persons' # Note the Plural 
    ) 
    # Related name for a FK is a one-to-many relationship 
    # (i.e. 1 User can be first_person on many threads) 
    # This may not be your desired behaviour, but it is possible on current set-up
    
    second_person = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='thread_second_persons'
    ) # As above
    
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        related_name='user_profile'
    )
    # Note: custom_user is confusing nomenclature. 
    # The above is best practice for User <> UserProfile 1-to-1 relationships
    picture = models.ImageField(
        default='profile_image/pro.png', 
        upload_to='profile_image', 
        blank=True
    )
```

Now when you want access to the `UserProfile` from the `Thread` object, you can do so as follows inside a template:

`{{ thread.second_person.user_profile.picture }}`

Side Note: in your views.py file, if you are sending just the `thread` to your template, then to save your database several queries I would optimise with the following `select_related` parameters:

```py
#views.py

threads = Thread.objects.select_related(
    'first_person', 'first_person__user_profile', 
    'second_person', 'second_person__user_profile'
).all()

thread = Thread.objects.select_related(
    'first_person', 'first_person__user_profile', 
    'second_person', 'second_person__user_profile'
).get(id=id)
```